# Appium stopped working after executing test for the first time

Tags: android, selenium, adb, appium, android-uiautomator

I was able to run tests both on Nox emulator and real device. But it happened , may be after I installed some software, Charles may be, that the test executed once on the Nox emulator and then it started giving the errors in Appium log and then I tried on real device and it worked once and then didn't work after that.

**What I tried**:

- Spend whole day reading existing answers and trying different
  solutions
- Uninstall all proxy related applications
- Update Appium Versions
- Try different ports on appium
- Update java clients for appium, selenium and so
- Reinstall SDK

Running Appiumg with the following capabilities

```
        File app = new File("app.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","7.0");

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");

        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", !fresh);
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

        try {
            return new AppiumDriver(new URL(appiumPath), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It installs Appium Settings app and the app to be tested successfully. But doesn't proceed further.

**Appium Log**: https://pastebin.com/vU5mZJCh

Answer (score 0):

The error indicate that your desired capabilities are wrong.

Remove this line.

```
capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
```

Refer to below link for more info :
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Updated the capabilities in the question

Comment: Have you try adding only the bare minimum caps and test it out? There seem to be some extra caps in above.